# Using double negation - For what reason?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yesterday it have read this blog-article by John Resig: 
http://ejohn.org/blog/comparing-document-position/

This snippet I don't understand:

```
function contains(a, b){
  return a.contains ?
    a != b && a.contains(b) :
    !!(a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & 16);
}
```

The first expression is clear: If a isn't identical with b and b is contained in a then return true.
But what is the purpose of the two-times negation in the second expression?
The return of compareDocumentPosition() is bitwise compared with 16. => Results either in 16 or 0. Let's say it is 16 then it becomes false after the first negation. Then true again after the second negation. 
In case of 0 it becomes true and then false again.

Does anyone understand the code and can explain it?

Comment: So that it returned a boolean, not a number.

Comment: Okay. Makes sense. I guess I've been stucked. Thanks. Do you want to turn your comment into an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double negation operator is used to convert as boolean.. think of it as a similar method to `parseInt()`

Here's a related [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)